# No puedo actualizar la version de Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Quiero actualizar la versión de ruby on rails.
Estoy usando ubuntu y cuando ejecuto:

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.7.1
```

Me dice que tengo la versión 4.2.7.1 instalada.

Para actualizar a la versión que quiero uso el comando:

```
sudo gem install rails -v 5.1.4
Successfully installed rails-5.1.4
Parsing documentation for rails-5.1.4
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Pero cuando vuelvo a ejecutar el comando rails -v para verificar la versión, me sigue mostrando la anterior

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.7.1
```

Alguien sabe como puedo arreglarlo, lo mismo me sucede en Mac Os X

Comment: ¿Quieres actualizar la gema en tu máquina o la quieres actualizar en un proyecto/app existente?, ¿cuántas versiones de ruby tienes instaladas?, ¿qué manejador de versiones utilizas?

Comment: Quiero actualizar la gema en mi máquina, ya encontré una solución, tanto para mac como para linux, con las siguientes instrucciones se soluciona: curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
rvm install "ruby-2.3.1"

rvm gemset create rails-5.1.4
rvm use 2.3.1@rails-5.1.4 --default
gem install rails

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar las versiones de *Rails* que tienes instaladas en tu sistema (para la versión de *Ruby* activa al momento), simplemente ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
$ gem list rails
```

Este comando te mostrará las gemas que contengan `rails` en su nombre, sólo encuentra la gema `rails` la cual mostrará, entre paréntesis, todas las versiones instaladas; por ejemplo, el resultado en mi máquina es este:

```
rails (5.1.3, 5.1.1, 5.1.0, 5.0.2, 5.0.1, 5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.8, 4.2.6, 4.2.1)
```

Entonces, si ejecuto `rails -v` en un directorio donde **no he instalado/creado una aplicación de *Rails***, obtendré la última versión instalada; en mi caso este sería el resultado:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.1.3
```

Sin embargo, si ejecuto el comando desde un directorio donde **existe una aplicación de *Rails***, entonces me mostrará la versión con la que haya creado esa aplicación (i.e. la que esté especificada en el *Gemfile* de la aplicación); por ejemplo:

```
$ cd rails_4_app
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.1
```

Si creas una nueva aplicación deberás especificar la versión de *Rails* que quieres utilizar, de lo contrario se creará la aplicación con la versión más reciente que tengas; por ejemplo:

```
$ rails _4.2.1_ new mi_app_con_rails_4
```

Si lo que buscas es actualizar la versión de *Rails* en una **aplicación existente**, entonces debes actualizar el *Gemfile* de la aplicación, indicando la versión de *Rails* a la que quieres actualizar (no es necesario tener la gema instalada en tu máquina):

```
# Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

rails gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
# otras gemas
```

Y, una vez actualizado el *Gemfile*, actualiza la instalación de la nueva gema con *bundler*:

```
$ bundle install
```

**IMPORTANTE**

Actualizar la versión de *Rails* en una aplicación existente no es una tarea trivial y, si no se hace de manera ordenada, puede ser una verdadera pesadilla (dependiendo la complejidad de la aplicación).

Por lo tanto, si vas a actualizar una aplicación, te recomiendo (como mínimo) lo siguiente:

- Tener al día tu *suite* de pruebas
- Actualizar una versión a la vez (por ejemplo, en tu caso lo haría en este orden: *4.2.9* > *5.0.6* > *5.1.4*)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando instales rails, no utilices el comando `sudo` porque de lo contrario, algunas de las funciones te van a quedar disponibles solamente para usuario sudo y no para un usuario normal, o empezarás a ver errores aleatorios o cuyos mensajes no sean claros.

Si acabas de empezar con rails, te recomiendo que trates de desinstalar todo y al empezar de nuevo, cualquier cosa que no requiera `apt-get` la lances sin sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes actualizar la version de rails en el Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
```

Luego realizar

```
bundle install
```

y aplicará esa gema, si no existe la descargará y la instalará.

Actualmente estás instalando las gemas manualmente. El Gemfile es una archivo donde se listan todas las gemas que se instalarán en el proyecto y `bundle install` el comando que las instala. Por esa razón este es el método más conveniente.